# Switch camera on webview video call

Tags: xamarin.forms, webrtc, peerjs

I have app in xamarin form where i am accessing webview for video call. Everything is working fine just i need to know how i can switch back/front camera during call? as when video call start front camera open by default.

Code for initializing video call

```
function initializeLocalMedia(options, callback) {

        if(options) {
            options['audio'] = true;

            if(options['video'])
                options['video'] = true;
        } else {
            options['audio'] = true;
            options['video'] = false;
        }

        // Get audio/video stream
        navigator.getUserMedia(options, function(stream) {
            // Set your video displays
            window.localStream = stream;
            myapp.setMyVideo(window.localStream)
            if(callback)
                callback();
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
            alert('Unable to call ' + err.name)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide a working code with webview video call implementation for xamarin forms? Sounds very interesting, and could help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Going straight to code then it should look like:

```
Camera.CameraInfo camInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo ();
for (int i = 0; i < Camera.NumberOfCameras; i++) {
    Camera.GetCameraInfo (i, camInfo);
    if (camInfo.Facing == CameraFacing.Front){
        try {
            return Camera.Open(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log or something
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

What we are doing is iterating over the hardware and then check to match the front camera, if it match then do the things. Same is true for back camera too

Comment: how you are getting this 'Camera.CameraInfo '? i dont get any reference on my project with camera

Comment: this code is for xamarin.android i am using xamarin form

Comment: @KulsumInternationalHospital Then you need to get a media plugin rather than bulding everything from core. For startup consider reading https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-with-the-media-plugin-for-xamarin/

Comment: in media plugin it doesnt give any option to select camera

Comment: Are you using Form for android app?

Comment: xamarin form, i need to flip camera during call and i am using xamarin form in which webview is working for video call

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283221/how-to-flip-camera-used-by-zxing-in-xamaring-forms
does this helped?